Autosize columns based on the data size in each column BootstrapTable version 1.22.1
Is there a method that would auto set the width based on the data size in each column?
bootstrapTable Version: 1.22.1
I have tried:
$bucketdetailtable.bootstrapTable("showLoading")

... AjAX code ...

$bucketdetailtable.bootstrapTable("hideLoading")
$bucketdetailtable.bootstrapTable("load",devices)
$bucketdetailtable.bootstrapTable("resetView")

resetView does not adjust column width.
However if I add
data-show-toggle="true"
When I click on the toggle and toggle back the view is perfect.
I have also added 'data-width="xx"' on columns i know the fixed size and will not change. But I rather have bootstrapTable set the size.
I'm trying to avoid column wraps since there is plenty of room in other columns.
